# Unpacking nested list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, product, python-itertools, nested-lists

I'm trying to get all possible combinations for each list in a nested list.
I've tried the following code below,  but it is printing an empty list

```py
import json
from pprint import pprint
import itertools


variant = [[{"Typ": "Bridge"}, {"Typ": "Media"}, {"Typ": "Tower"}], [{"Kabeleinf\u00fchrung": "Kabelverschraubung Kunststoff \u00d8 79 mm"}, {"Kabeleinf\u00fchrung": "Power T\u00fclle Twist \u00d8 80 mm"}, {"Kabeleinf\u00fchrung": "Power Grommet Twist USB Daten / Ladung \u00d8 80 mm"}, {"Kabeleinf\u00fchrung": "Power T\u00fclle GST 18 \u00d8 80 mm"}], [{"Whiteboard": "Ohne"}, {"Whiteboard": "Mitt"}], [{"::gote::gote::@GGOTE_WhiteboardShelf": "Ohne"}, {"::gote::gote::@GGOTE_WhiteboardShelf": "Mitt"}], [{"TV-Halterung": "Ohne"}, {"TV-Halterung": "Mitt"}], [], [{"Stoff": "Event screen + (Preisklasse 1)"}, {"Stoff": "Cara (Preisklasse 1)"}, {"Stoff": "Carlow (Preisklasse 1)"}, {"Stoff": "Pearl (Preisklasse 1)"}, {"Stoff": "Omega (Preisklasse 1)"}, {"Stoff": "Xpress (Preisklasse 1)"}, {"Stoff": "Hush (Preisklasse 1)"}, {"Stoff": "Mica (Preisklasse 1)"}, {"Stoff": "Slope (Preisklasse 1)"}, {"Stoff": "Noble Lux (Preisklasse 2)"}, {"Stoff": "Houston Reflect (Preisklasse 2)"}, {"Stoff": "Kunstleder (Preisklasse 2)"}, {"Stoff": "Lido (Preisklasse 2)"}, {"Stoff": "Twist (Preisklasse 2)"}, {"Stoff": "Rivet (preisklasse 2)"}, {"Stoff": "Blazer (Preisklasse 3)"}, {"Stoff": "Blazer Lite (pris gruppe 3)"}, {"Stoff": "Synergy (Preisklasse 3)"}, {"Stoff": "Bond (Preisklasse 3)"}, {"Stoff": "Hint (Preisklasse 3)"}, {"Stoff": "Remix 3 (preisklasse 4)"}, {"Stoff": "Step (Preisklasse 4)"}], [{"Stofffarbe": "01 (60000 BY GABRIEL)"}, {"Stofffarbe": "02 (61008 BY GABRIEL)"}, {"Stofffarbe": "03 (61011 BY GABRIEL)"}, {"Stofffarbe": "04 (60004 BY GABRIEL)"}, {"Stofffarbe": "05 (60002 BY GABRIEL)"}, {"Stofffarbe": "06 (60021 BY GABRIEL)"}, {"Stofffarbe": "07 (60999 BY GABRIEL)"}, {"Stofffarbe": "08 (67015 BY GABRIEL)"}, {"Stofffarbe": "09 (67017 BY GABRIEL)"}], [{"Type": "110010"}]]

print(list(itertools.product(*variant)))
```

this is my current code.

```
[('Typ--Bridge','Kabeleinführung--Kabelverschraubung Kunststoff Ø 79 mm', 'Whiteboard--Ohne'),('Typ--Bridge','Kabeleinführung--Kabelverschraubung Kunststoff Ø 79 m', 'Whiteboard--Mitt'),('Typ--Bridge', 'Kabeleinführung--Power Tülle Twist Ø 80 mm', 'Whiteboard--Ohne'), ('Typ--Bridge', 'Kabeleinführung--Power Tülle Twist Ø 80 mm',
'Whiteboard--Mitt'),
```

this is what I want the output to look like.
It seems the problem is in the unpacking of the nested lists, which when I run separately isn't separated by commas, but I just can't figure out what is wrong exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the lengths of all the elements in `variant`. You'll see that one of them has length zero.

```
In [13]: [len(i) for i in variant]
Out[13]: [3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 0, 22, 9, 1]
```

This empty list should be removed from your input. `itertools.product` takes one element from every one of its arguments in each of its output values, so any empty lists will cause it to return no results.